# Flutter how to test if ui.Image is empty or null correctly?

Tags: flutter, paint, isnull

I define globally a variable as `ui.Image _img1Global = null as ui.Image;` then I wanted to check to determine if the value is null or not.

```
if (_img1Global != null as ui.Image) {
              canvasWrapper.save();
              canvasWrapper.drawImage(
                  _img1Global, Offset(x, y - 2), new Paint());
              canvasWrapper.restore();
            }
```

I want to check if it is not null then I want to operate the drawImage but I keep getting error as `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Image' in type cast` at this if statement ? How to check if its filled with ui.Image and check its correct type?

I have even try this

```
_img1Global != null as ui.Image
                ? print("is null")
                : print("is not null");
```

still I am getting same error ?

Answer (score 1):

```
null as ui.Image
```

It is throwing an error because the above code is telling that set `null` type as an `Image` type

To check the type of a variable use the **runtimeType** operator

```
if (_img1Global.runtimeType == Image) print('True')
```

Comment: @Its giving me the same still even I though I add a late keyword. How to resolve this ya ?

Comment: what do you mean by late keyword?

Comment: ok what I meant is that at the out side I tried this late ui.Image _img1Global = null as ui.Image;

Comment: Try the method which i have suggested above

Comment: I have tried it gives me same error though